# Your Paypal Adaptive AppID

Tags: wordpress, paypal

Am working on a Wordpress Theme called freelanceengine to setup my Paypal Escrow account. I need help create API Credentials and Live APP ID

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please review [StackOverflow - How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) with regards to the way you should ask and what your question should include. You should show attempts of code in your question so that members of the community can assist you and provide you with more accurate responses.

Answer (score 0):

Adaptive Payments is a very old product that has been deprecated since December of 2017. No live Adaptive APP IDs are available.

Use a supported service instead, such as PayPal Checkout.